# Wrap items for last row in flex layout with space between alignment

Tags: html, angular, css, flexbox

Is there any way to have wraped items in rows with space between alignment, where last row dont have big gap?

```
<div fxFlex="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-around">
    <my-item *ngFor="let item of items"></my-item>
</div>
```

Actual behaviour:

[image]

I need same "space-between" in last row compared to other rows.
[image]

Comment: That "big gap" is there because you only have 3 items on your last row. The space is still even between them. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Could you edit your post with code using these guidelines: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you have the HTML structure for it? Just want to know if all are inside the same parent or different parents per row?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to get what you're looking for is to add an empty element after the last visible element:

```html
<!-- your last 3 boxes -->
<div class="gray-box">
  (your content)
</div>

<div class="gray-box">
  (your content)
</div>

<div class="gray-box">
  (your content)
</div>

<!-- an empty box - make sure .transparent has opacity: 0-->
<div class="gray-box transparent"></div>
```

If you're okay with not using flexbox, `display: grid` is more along the lines of what you're looking for, where you can define grid sizes more strictly:

```css
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%);
grid-gap: /* gap between your items */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "filler" elements. You need 3 elements at the end of your list which are no visible. Everytime when your row breaks the filler helping to keep the right sizes and spaces.

```js
const addbutton = document.getElementsByClassName('add');

// referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);

const addEl = () => {
  const newli = document.createElement('li');
  newli.textContent = 'new flex child';
  const pos = document.querySelector('li.filler');
  pos.parentNode.insertBefore(newli, pos.previousElementSibling.nextSibling);
}

addbutton[0].addEventListener('click', addEl);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

ul>li {
  flex: 0 1 24%;
  background: #ccc;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul>li.filler {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button class="add">click here to add childs</button>
<ul>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li>lorem</li>
  <li class="filler"></li>
  <li class="filler"></li>
  <li class="filler"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, but number of elements can be changed based on API.

Comment: Thats no problem. The three filler need to be static. The normal flex childs can produced dynamicly. 

You can test it. Make different rows and you will see, that the spaces are always fine.

Comment: I have edit my snippet and added some JavaScript to demonstrate you, that this solution works with dynamic elements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing on your html and css structure here, but I assume you have something like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

You can keep the same spacing around each element by using a simple margin and setting the `justify-content` attribute to either `center` or `flex-start` based on your needs.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```